# Para que serve a propriedade Expect100Continue em System.Net.ServicePointManager?

Tags: c#, web-service, winforms

Estou trabalhando em um sistema que faz o gerenciamento das licenças dos clientes.

Existe um recurso no meu sistema para retornar a product key do cliente , fazendo uma consulta no **Web Service**.

E simples você informa o CNPJ ele retorna o a product key.

```
//Web Service
Gerencial.WebService.WSLicenca ws = new WebService.WSLicenca();

//Key
string ProductKey = ws.RetornaLicenca(CpfCnpj);
```

Mas ao realizar está operação e exibida  a mensagem de 
**Erro** :

> The request failed with HTTP status 417: Expectation failed

Segundo este [artigo](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/94235/The-request-failed-with-HTTP-status-417-Expectatio) a solução para este problema seria adicionar a propiedade [Expect100Continue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.expect100continue(v=vs.100).aspx)  definindo valor como `falso` , que pode ser feito pelo arquivo de configuração ou no trecho de código antes de fazer a consulta pelo Web Service.

**Código**

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
```

**Configuração**

```
 <configuration>
      <system.net>
         <settings>
          <servicePointManager expect100Continue="false" />
         </settings>
        </system.net>
 </configuration>
```

**Alguém pode me dizer para que isso serve ?**

Usando esta propriedade o erro foi corrigido mas não faço a minima ideia do que essa propriedade faz.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O código 100 é um status do protocolo HTTP.

O seu propósito é permitir a um cliente, antes de enviar o conteúdo (body) de uma requisição para o servidor, enviar os cabeçalhos (header) para que o servidor já determine se irá ou não aceitar a requisição completa.

Em alguns casos é muito ineficiente, principalmente quando o conteúdo a ser enviado para o servidor for muito grande, o servidor receber a requisição e rejeitá-la em seguida, sem nem olhar para o conteúdo.

No .NET, ao especificar que não estará usando esse comportamento (Expect100Continue = false), o cliente já sabe que não vai esperar essa resposta antecipada do servidor antes de enviar o conteúdo completo.

Leia aqui a especificação da W3C sobre esse comportamento:
https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.2.3